# Google suggest and auto complete with jquery/ajax in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, google-suggest

I would like to get some ref to use Jquery in Rails app.
At the moment, I am stuck to find the things to enable google suggest in text box and autocomplete in Rails app. Any help/suggestions/ref would be of great help.

Answer (score 3):

I did a short search on auto-complete with Rails earlier today and these are the best links I found:

- http://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete and http://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-app
- http://blog.jackhq.com/posts/3-how-to-add-jquery-autocomplete-to-your-rails-forms-in-a-restful-way
- http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/

Edit: I just implemented the first link in my app, works flawless so far. I had minor problems with the documentation though, this works for me (on typing AutoComplete starts after the second character):

Model named Category, has an attribute name:

controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :category, :name
  ...
```

routes:

```
get 'users/autocomplete_category_name'
```

view:

```
<%= form_tag 'users/index' do %>
  <%= autocomplete_field_tag 'address', '', users_autocomplete_category_name_path, :size => 75 %>
<% end %>
```